# Is there a better way to use assigned variables from my 'if' function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope, global

I am fairly new to javascript, and I have been having trouble with this 'if' function. It is supposed to assign a value to a variable based on submitted form data. Here's my code:

```html
var carSurv = {};





global.survValue = function(){
            if ((req.body.price == 10000)){
               carSurv.price= 1;
            } else if((req.body.price == 20000)){
                carSurv.price= 2;
            } else if((req.body.price == 30000)){
                carSurv.price= 3;
            } else if((req.body.price == 40000)){
                carSurv.price= 4;
            } else if((req.body.price == 50000)){
                carSurv.price= 5;
            } else if((req.body.price === 'above 50000')){
                carSurv.price= 6;
            };
            if ((req.body.seat == 2) ){
                carSurv.seat= 2;
            } else if((req.body.seat == 4)){
                carSurv.seat= 4;
            } else if((req.body.seat == 5)){
                carSurv.seat= 5;
            } else if((req.body.seat == 7)){
                carSurv.seat= 7;
            } else if((req.body.seat == 8)){
                carSurv.seat= 8;
            }; 
            if ((req.body.carType === 'Compact' )){
                carSurv.body= 'compact';
            } else if((req.body.carType === 'Sedan')){
                carSurv.body= 'sedan';
            } else if((req.body.carType === 'SUV')){
                carSurv.body= 'suv';
            } else if((req.body.carType === 'Truck')){
                carSurv.body= 'truck';
            } else if((req.body.carType === 'Sports')){
                carSurv.body= 'sports';
            };
            if ((req.body.personality === 'Chill')){
                carSurv.personality= 'chill';
            } else if((req.body.personality === 'Compassionate')){
                carSurv.personality= 'compassionate';
            } else if((req.body.personality === 'Assertive')){
                carSurv.personality= 'assertive';
            } else if((req.body.personality === 'Short-tempered')){
                carSurv.personality= 'angry';
            };
            if ((req.body.activity === 'Family roadtrips and outgoing' )){
                carSurv.activity= 'roadtrip';
            } else if((req.body.activity === 'Going to music festivals')){
                carSurv.activity= 'music';
            } else if((req.body.activity === 'Commuting to work')){
                carSurv.activity= 'commute';
            } else if((req.body.activity === 'Date nights for two')){
                carSurv.activity= 'date';
            };
            if ((req.body.driving === 'Being Safe' )){
                carSurv.driving= 'safe';
            } else if((req.body.driving === 'Getting from point A to point B')){
                carSurv.driving= 'point';
            } else if((req.body.driving === 'Going fast')){
                carSurv.driving= 'fast';
            } else if((req.body.driving === 'Looking good while doing it')){
                carSurv.driving= 'looks';
            } else if((req.body.driving === 'Having the ability to drive with groups')){
                carSurv.driving= 'passengers';
            };
            if ((req.body.attributes === 'Longevity: Car durability, Gas mileage/Fuel efficiency' )){
                carSurv.attrib= 'stam';
               
            } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Versatility: Off-road and work use')){
                carSurv.attrib= 'vers';
                
            } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Exterior Design: Look and style purely to impress')){
                carSurv.attrib= 'style';
                
            } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Internal Design: Spacious and compact')){
                carSurv.attrib= 'comfort';
                
            } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Brand name manufacturing: American or foreign made')){
                carSurv.attrib= 'mfg';
                
            }
        
        };
        console.log(carSurv.attrib);
```

It's abridged a bit, but this is the area I'm mainly concerned about. The console.log i'm using for testing keeps returning 'undefined'. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      global.survValue = function(){
        if ((req.body.price > 50000)){
           carSurv.price= req.body.price/10000;
        } else if((req.body.price < 50000)){
            carSurv.price= 6;
        };
         carSurv.seat= req.body.seat;
         carSurv.body= req.body.carType;
         
         carSurv.personality= req.body.personality;
        if((req.body.personality === 'Short-tempered')){
            carSurv.personality= 'angry';
        };
        
        if ((req.body.activity === 'Family roadtrips and outgoing' )){
            carSurv.activity= 'roadtrip';
        } else if((req.body.activity === 'Going to music festivals')){
            carSurv.activity= 'music';
        } else if((req.body.activity === 'Commuting to work')){
            carSurv.activity= 'commute';
        } else if((req.body.activity === 'Date nights for two')){
            carSurv.activity= 'date';
        };
        if ((req.body.driving === 'Being Safe' )){
            carSurv.driving= 'safe';
        } else if((req.body.driving === 'Getting from point A to point B')){
            carSurv.driving= 'point';
        } else if((req.body.driving === 'Going fast')){
            carSurv.driving= 'fast';
        } else if((req.body.driving === 'Looking good while doing it')){
            carSurv.driving= 'looks';
        } else if((req.body.driving === 'Having the ability to drive with groups')){
            carSurv.driving= 'passengers';
        };
        if ((req.body.attributes === 'Longevity: Car durability, Gas mileage/Fuel efficiency' )){
            carSurv.attrib= 'stam';
           
        } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Versatility: Off-road and work use')){
            carSurv.attrib= 'vers';
            
        } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Exterior Design: Look and style purely to impress')){
            carSurv.attrib= 'style';
            
        } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Internal Design: Spacious and compact')){
            carSurv.attrib= 'comfort';
            
        } else if((req.body.attributes === 'Brand name manufacturing: American or foreign made')){
            carSurv.attrib= 'mfg';
            
        }
    };
    console.log(carSurv.attrib);
```

You can use some login something like this. there is no need to put too many if conditions

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it really cleaned up my code